# why clang++ behaves differently from clang since the former is a symbol link of the latter?

Tags: linux, macos, clang, symlink, clang++

I have a C program that tries to modify a const string literal. As now I learned that this is not allowed.

When I compile the code with `clang test.c` the compiler gives no warning. But when I compile it with `clang++ test.c` it gives a warning:

> test.c:6:15: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
>         [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
>       char *s = "hello world";
>                 ^

The problem is that it turns out `clang++` is just a symbol link of `clang`:

```
ll `which clang++`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  5 Jan  1 12:34 /usr/bin/clang++@ -> clang
```

So my question is how could `clang++` behaves differently from `clang` given that it's a symbol link of `clang`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clang is looking at its `argv[0]` and altering its behavior depending on what it sees.  This is an uncommon and discouraged, but not rare, trick going at least as far back as 4.2BSD `ex` and `vi`, which were the same executable, and probably farther.

In this case, `clang` is compiling your `.c` file as C, and `clang++` is compiling it as C++.  This is a historical wart which you should not rely on; use the appropriate compiler command *and* make sure that your file extension reflects the true contents of the file.

Comment: Do you mean that _bash_ is looking at `argv[0]` and altering the behavior? So it's hard coded in bash that `clang++` behaves differently from `clang`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think enough. It's hard coded in `clang`. Thank you:)

Comment: Could I get a citation on this technique being "uncommon and discouraged"? Not meaning to bash, just curious.

Comment: I'm not aware of citations for the 'uncommon' part, but [here's one fairly influential place where it's discouraged](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/User-Interfaces.html) with the rationale that you never know when the end user might want to rename a program without changing its behavior, e.g. because you have two different compilers and they can't both be `/usr/bin/cc`.

Answer (score 5):

By convention, the name by which a command is invoked is passed as `argv[0]`; it is not especially unusual for programs to change their behavior based on this.  (Historically, `ln`, `cp`, and `mv` were hardlinks to the same executable on Research Unix and used `argv[0]` to decide which action to do.  Also, most shells look for a leading `-` in `argv[0]` to decide if they should be a login shell.)  Often there is also some other way to get the same effect (options, environment variables, etc.); you should in general use this instead of playing `argv[0]` games.

There are reasons to do this, but in most cases it's not a good idea to rely on it or to design programs around it.