# What's the difference between clang and clang++ when building a library?

Tags: linker, clang, clang++

I was compiling a c library (to be used by a c++ project) with clang. I got linker errors (specifically, undefined symbol regarding the hqxInit function) when trying to link this library. When I switch to clang++, it works. Checking with nm, clang++ munges the names further. What is going on—and is there a better way to tell the linker that a library is munged-for-c versus munged-for-c++? It seems silly to have to build a c library with c++....

// built with clang

```
$ nm libhqx.a

libhqx.bak(init.c.o)
04000000 C _RGBtoYUV
00000004 C _YUV1
00000004 C _YUV2
00000000 T _hqxInit
```

// built with clang++

```
$ nm libhqx.a 

libhqx.a(init.o):
00000100 S _RGBtoYUV
04000100 S _YUV1
04000104 S _YUV2
00000000 T __Z7hqxInitv
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`clang` and `clang++` on most systems are the same executable. One is merely a symbolic link to the other.

The program checks to see what name it is invoked under, and:

- for `clang`, compiles code as C
- for `clang++`, compiles code as C++

In C++, the compiler generates names for functions differently than C - this is because you can have multiple functions with the same name (but different) parameters. This is called "name mangling" - and that's what you are seeing.

You can use a tool called `c++filt` to "demangle" the names.

Example:

```
$ c++filt __Z7hqxInitv
hqxInit()
```

More information here: [why clang++ behaves differently from clang since the former is a symbol link of the latter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359624/why-clang-behaves-differently-from-clang-since-the-former-is-a-symbol-link-of?rq=1)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! "name mangling" is a great search term for digging deeper into it.

Comment: You can override clang/clang++ executable-name-based language autodetect behavior using `--driver-mode` command-line parameter. For example, `clang --driver-mode=g++`  should be equivalent to `clang++`.